# Looking for a matlab function that can "magnify" a given matrix by a given-times

Tags: matlab

I'm looking for a matlab built-in function that can "magnify" a given matrix by a given-times. For example, if given matrix `a=[1 2;3 4]` and magnify factor 3, the output of the function should be:

```
1 1 1 2 2 2
1 1 1 2 2 2
1 1 1 2 2 2
3 3 3 4 4 4
3 3 3 4 4 4
3 3 3 4 4 4
```

I can write the function by myself, but I wonder if matlab provides any built-in function that implements the same function so that I can magnify a matrix using a simple line. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you're looking for is called `imresize` (with the `'nearest'` flag) and is part of the image processing toolbox:

```
>> imresize([1,2;3,4],2,'nearest')
ans =
     1     1     2     2
     1     1     2     2
     3     3     4     4
     3     3     4     4
```